# Speedup relationship and node creation using cypher in Neo4j

Tags: java, performance, neo4j, cypher, query-performance

i have 2 csv files A and B.
File A contains 7000 rows with 6 properties and File B contains 10M rows with 11 properties.
Moreover, File A has the property PKA which is used as primary key, whereas File B has the property FKA which is used as foreign key respect to PKA.

I want to load these files into Neo4j in this way:
1 - insert a new node for each row of File A and File B
2 - add a relationship between any node created that represents the relationship primary and foreign key described.

Currently, I have inserted these files with BatchInserter using the JAVA API adding a node for each row of these files and setting the labels "A" and "B" for File A and file B respectively.
I have also create two index for PKA and FKA.
To add the relationships my intention is to call the following cypher statement (from Neo4jShell):

```
match (a:A), (b:B) where a.PKA=b.FKB create (a)<-[:KEYREL]-(b);
```

My problems are:
- adding the nodes with BatchInserter takes 14minutes for File B (the biggest one) with only one commit at the end (~12k nodes/sec, ~130k properties/sec), I want to speedup the import process of a factor of 2.
- the cypher query can't be handled with this dataset size but i would like to make is possible.

Im running on a VM with an IntelXeon @2.6Ghz dual core and 8GB RAM with Windows 64bit and Java8 64 bit installed.
I have run my import java program and Neo4jShell with the following java options:

```
-server -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Xms2000m -Xmx5000m
```

Comment: don't forget to remove the FKB after you created the relationships

Answer (score 1):

Running MATCH is typically quite slow when employed on a large volume of data.

You could try to speed it up creating a [constraint](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-constraints.html) on the nodes, wherein you define each node as unique. This can [speed up the MATCH](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/cypherdoc-importing-csv-files-with-cypher.html?_ga=1.248141135.953156972.1370702221) operation, though it does also take time to create the constraint:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (a:A) ASSERT a.PKA IS UNIQUE;
CREATE INDEX ON :B(PKB);
```

You can then run the MATCH, which you can run from a third CSV file per the [Neo4j docs](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/cypherdoc-importing-csv-files-with-cypher.html?_ga=1.248141135.953156972.1370702221) which describe a similar scenario to yours.

Comment: Also your operation for inserting the relationships should be different, `MATCH (a:A) MATCH (b:B) where b.FKB=a.PKA create (a)<-[:KEYREL]-(b);` You might have to add `USING INDEX ON b:B(FKB)` after the second match

Comment: Thank you for your replies! I have already noticed the unique constraint but It seems to be slow and it takes the whole memory available.
Right now I am trying to set relationships directly during the import process using import-cypher shell command. This command is mutch slower but it takes 1GB of ram at most and it is more versatile, there is a way to speedup this command?

Comment: For speed the best option appears to be using the [embedded Java API](http://www.neo4j.org/develop/java) directly if you can. i.e. avoid REST

Comment: @MichaelHunger i have tried your cypher query with two match statements but it returns me null, it runs only with my query.
The indexes are correctly loaded.